# as3 MOUSE_UP stopDrag() not functioning

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseup

I am working on a basic as3 slingshot game which uses startDrag() and stopDrag() to let the user pull an object and fire. when the object is not stretching the "elastic" the MOUSE_UP function works as it should, but when it is below the set points and is stretching the string the MOUSE_UP function is not being called.

- vars

  ```
  var gravity = 0.1;
  var angle1:Number = 0;
  var angle2:Number = 0;
  var radius:Number = 1;
  var elasticCoefficient:Number = 0.002;
  var released:Boolean = true;
  var forced:Boolean = false;
  var acc:Object = {x:0 , y:0}; 
  var vel:Object = {x:0 , y:0};
  var elastic:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
  ```
- the ENTER_FRAME code is

  ```
  function doConstantly(e:Event):void
  {
      acc.x = 0;
      acc.y = gravity;

      if(released == true) 
      {
          vel.x += acc.x; 
          vel.y += acc.y; 
          ball.x += vel.x;
          ball.y += vel.y
      }


      if(ball.y > stage.stageHeight + 500 || ball.y < -50)
      {
          resetLevel();
      }


      elastic.graphics.clear();
      elastic.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xFFF2BD);


      if(ball.y > point1.y && ball.x < point2.x)
      {
              forced = true;

          var x1:Number = ball.x - point1.x;
          var y1:Number = ball.y - point1.y;
          var x2:Number = point2.x - ball.x;
          var y2:Number = point2.y - ball.y;
          var distance1:Number = Math.sqrt(x1 * x1 + y1 * y1);
          var distance2:Number = Math.sqrt(x2 * x2 + y2 * y2);
          angle1 = Math.atan2(y1,x1);
          angle2 = Math.atan2(y2,x2);
          var xOffset:Number = Math.cos(angle1 + Math.PI / 2) * radius;
          var yOffset:Number = Math.sin(angle1 + Math.PI / 2) * radius;
          var xOffset2:Number = Math.cos(angle2 + Math.PI / 2) * radius;
          var yOffset2:Number = Math.sin(angle2 + Math.PI / 2) * radius;
          angle1 +=  Math.sin(radius / distance1);
          angle2 +=  Math.sin(radius / distance2) * -1;
          elastic.graphics.moveTo(point1.x, point1.y);
          elastic.graphics.lineTo(ball.x+xOffset, ball.y+yOffset);
          elastic.graphics.moveTo(point2.x, point2.y);
          elastic.graphics.lineTo(ball.x+xOffset2, ball.y+yOffset2);
      }
      else
      {
          forced = false;

          if(forced == true){trace("forced is true")}
          if(forced == false){trace("forced is false")}
          elastic.graphics.moveTo(point1.x, point1.y);
          elastic.graphics.lineTo(point2.x, point2.y);
      }

      if (released == true && forced == true)
      {
          acc.x +=  distance1 * Math.sin(angle2) * elasticCoefficient;
          acc.y +=   -  distance1 * Math.cos(angle1) * elasticCoefficient;
          acc.x +=  distance2 * Math.sin(angle1) * elasticCoefficient;
          acc.y +=   -  distance2 * Math.cos(angle2) * elasticCoefficient;

          vel.x +=  acc.x;
          vel.y +=  acc.y;
      }
  }
  ```
- and the mouse events

  ```
  function ballMouseDown(event:MouseEvent)
  {
  //call function to reset level
  resetLevel();
  //follow mouse
  ball.x = mouseX;
  ball.y = mouseY;
  ball.startDrag();
  //set released to false so that gravity wont affect the ball when clicked
  released = false;
  }
  function ballMouseUp(event:MouseEvent)
  {
  trace("mouse up function called")
  released = true; //gravity will affect the ball when released
  ball.stopDrag();
  }
  ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the `MOUSE_UP` handler to the `stage` instead - at the moment, you will need to release your mouse while it is over the `ball` which may not be the case.

Update your `MOUSE_DOWN` handler to attach the listener to the stage:

```
function ballMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // ...your current code.

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, ballMouseUp);
}
```

And removing the listener when the handler is triggered:

```
function ballMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // ...your current code.

    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, ballMouseUp);
}
```

Comment: thats fixed it. thanks very much! i dont quite understand why the mouse would not register as being over the ball if it was when the ball is clicked and then the ball is being dragged with the mouse

Comment: @user2145312 The frame rate of your application is much slower than the rate of the mouse update on the system. This gives plenty of time each side of the frame being redrawn in your app for the mouse to actually not be in the same place as the ball.